# Updating a content type via feature receiver at the list definition level

Tags: list, content-type, list-definition

Problem is I am trying to update a content type (created within a **list definition**, going into a new list instance) and it is not liking the ID I pass in code.  I tried passing JUST the child ID, parent & child, and full (base, parent, child) ID.  All of these result in various errors (object reference error and format error).

I am updating in a seperate feature from the one that creates the list definition and new content type.

Why is this giving me trouble?  Here is a code snippet.

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("site"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPField field = web.Fields[new Guid("e93f5414-1486-481e-842d-696df0ff9ce6")];
                field.Group = "newAnimals";
                field.Update();

                SPContentType cType = web.ContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId("CE2744E3BAEA4734B2333D043AA5DD2C")];
                cType.Description = "Super cool content type";
                cType.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Again...this is at the **DEFINITION** level so I want to make one update to the content type the definition is implementing and have that change pushed to ALL content types being used within ANY list implementing this particular definition.

I do not want to do this via CAML, I am looking for the programmatic method.

Answer (score 1):

Your Content Type Id is in wrong format:

[Content Type IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822.aspx)

Isn't it maybe: 0x0100CE2744E3BAEA4734B2333D043AA5DD2C (if parent type is item)

**Edited**

By using [SPContentTypeCollection.BestMatch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypecollection.bestmatch.aspx) it is possible to avoid 'confusion' of what is the right ContentTypeId.

> Searches the collection and returns the content type identifier (ID)
>   that is the nearest match to the specified content type ID.

```
// id can be parent or even base content type
SPContentTypeId matchId = web.ContentTypes.BestMatch(id);
SPContentType cType = web.ContentTypes[matchId];
```

**About two feature issue**:

If one feature handles creation and another handles update then it is vital to activate them in right order. That is most likely your problem - you are trying to make update on Content type that still doesn't exist. Some more info on this issue:

- [Timing in SharePoint features deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477930/timing-in-sharepoint-features-deployment)
- [Feature Chaining: Activation Dependencies and Feature Stapling](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/tlingenfelder/archive/2009/06/05/feature-chaining-activation-dependencies-and-feature-stapling.aspx)

To make things simple: if you want to be sure make the third (master) feature which will activate other features in right order.

**Another addition**

Since it is list content type you are after for you need to use [SPList.ContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypes.aspx)  instead of [SPWeb.ContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypes.aspx).

Comment: I specified the following in the original question

"I tried passing JUST the child ID, parent & child, and full (base, parent, child) ID"

Comment: But you provided invalid code. `new  SPContentTypeId("CE2744E3BAEA4734B2333D043AA5DD2C")` will fail Also CT is originally created in web you are reffering to (SPSite("site")) ?

Comment: ......ok........


here you go:                     SPContentType cType = web.ContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId("0x0100CE2744E3BAEA4734B2333D043AA5DD2C")];

ALSO fails...

and yes, the content type was created in the site collection I am passing as a parameter.

Comment: Since you provided some additional info in comments I have updated my answer. I am not magician to instantly provide solution so it is vital to include all possible info (in reasonable limits) to avoid guessing (as my original answer was)

Comment: Apologies for getting frusterated, I thought the same as your last post and was fiddling around with activation order and I still seem to have the same issue.  It just cannot find the content type by any ID I pass it.  Also, activating a feature by the ID in the feature manifest (via code) fails - saying no feature can be found.

Comment: Did you try to find ct via UI after activation? Try to enumerate content types in web to see what you get (foreach on web.contentypes). Try to build another ct type. Verify ID and/or change it. Try to build another feature from scratch... all you can do is troubleshoot and all I can do is to give you some ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1474/discussion-between-dbobrowski-and-vedran-rasol)